# Why is Whitby missing in Fury of Dracula (FFG, 3ed)?

Tags: game-design, fury-of-dracula

Fury of Dracula mostly true to the book.

But one thing bugs me - Whitby is not on the board and is replaced by Manchester! Moreover, (real life) Manchester is in the west, not the east.

[image]

My question is, **have the designers ever commented on why Manchester replaces Whitby?**

Comment: Is there a particular reason you think Whitby is "missing"? Was it in previous editions?

Comment: @Thunderforge: Googling the images, it seems all eds have Manchester (none had Whitby), but the 1st had it in the West, above Liverpool. Might make sense as GW (1st ed) are UK based but FFG are US based?

Comment: So if none have Whitby, why do you think it should be there? Is it important in the source material or something? I mean, [Fontainebleau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontainebleau) isn't on the board either, but that doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Re "*it seems all eds have Manchester (none had Whitby)*", It appears that you answered your own question?

Comment: As for Manchester being too far East, it's surely to place space between it and Liverpool. At that scale, they would literally be on top of each other without the additional space. As they say on subway maps: "Map isn't to scale!"

Comment: @Thunderforge: Yep, I'd say Whitby is important in the book. It's where a significant part of the plot occurs and is the reason why at least one of the board game characters is hunting Dracula. If you ever go to Whitby, then you'll see the inhabitants think their town plays an important role in the book too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The lack of Whitby is consistent with earlier editions

#### First Edition

[image: Fury of Dracula, 1st Edition board]

#### Second Edition

[image: Fury of Dracula, 2nd Edition board]

In all these editions, Manchester exists in the United Kingdom region, but not Whitby.

However, Manchester is more or less in its proper location in both of these versions. It would appear that Manchester's seaside location in the 3rd edition is an error, perhaps in an effort to create more space on the board between it and Liverpool.

Or they confused it with [Manchester-by-the-Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester-by-the-Sea,_Massachusetts).

### There does not appear to be any designer statements about this change

Given that the game first came out in 1987, not a lot of information about its design or release is available online. In fact, the only reference I could find to Whitby in the game were players of the 3rd Edition with similar concerns as yours.

The game designer for the first edition (who has credit in later editions) is Stephen Hand. I thought about reaching out to him and asking about this, but it doesn't look like he has a website, Twitter, or other way to publicly contact him, so we're out of luck there.

If I were take a guess, the game was designed with some recognizable cities in mind, rather than a strict adherence to the source material. Besides, the first edition was released in 1987 and the internet and electronic books were still in their most primitive forms. It's quite possible that it was simply an oversight, and then later editions just remained consistent with earlier ones rather than correcting it.